# drupal_render radios missing name attribute

Tags: forms, theming

When rendering form type radios using drupal_get_form, each one of the radio's options can be exclusively selected, as the html name attribute is set to the parent's ('radios') id.

However I'm working on an ajax form module that integrates with mailchimp, and renders these form elements individually in isolation using drupal_render so they can be placed in a template.

My code to render radios is as follows:

```
$form_child = array (
  '#title' => 'Some Radios',
  '#weight' => '6',
  '#required' => false,
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array (
    'Option 1' => 'Option 1',
    'Option 2' => 'Option 2',
    'Option 3' => 'Option 3',
  ),
); // This is generated in my module

$form_child = form_process_radios($form_child);

$myhtml = drupal_render($form_child);
```

And here is what happens on my form:
[HTML output](http://cl.ly/image/2i3q2f1i1r2n/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-25%20at%2011.35.18%20AM.png)

[In the browser](http://f.cl.ly/items/0e2C372T2a2k231R0k0P/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-25%20at%2011.35.32%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1):

the function of the form_process_radios as given by the documentation is as follows

> Expands a radios element into individual radio elements.

So the out put you are getting is correct as per the documentation.

So in your case you dont need to call the form_process_radios. You can directly call the drupal_render function.

Comment: When I just call drupal_render, I get no radios showing at all.

Comment: Here's the html output http://f.cl.ly/items/2Z402T3K040N0C3e0u1J/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-25%20at%2011.52.53%20AM.png

Comment: you should set the attribute by adding the the following to the folm element $form['#attributes'] = array('name' => 'nameofradio); and yes you have to pass it through the form_process_radios as well

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour of the form api however. Look at all the form api examples for radios http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#radios There is clearly something not working right here, and setting the name attribute manually would not work in my case.

Comment: you could also try the theme_radios function

Comment: theme_radios does not work, looking at other code and examples drupal_render is the way to go, there's clearly something I'm missing here trying to get it to render however

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem eventually by calling drupal_process_form in hook_form_alter. Not sure if this is correct, but it works well and no extra steps are needed to get form elements rendering correctly. Any follow up or advice is appreciated. I'm sure that drupal_process_form is called in the drupal_get_form render path, just not sure of what hook to render custom parts in various locations. Probably theme_hook for the form, but it works well now for my purposes.